# Adjusting background-position of image pieces

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a puzzle out of a background image with numbered pieces. The pieces will eventually be movable with javascript. Right now, I'm stuck simply trying to position the pieces of this image. The html has a div with id called puzzlearea, and I have appended children with javascript, which I know works because it displays the new div pieces and their numbers. The CSS refuses to move the pieces relative to this background, and my two test pieces are stuck in the top left corner, seemingly ignoring my background-position values. Here is the CSS:

```
body {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: cursive;
   font-size: 14pt;
}

#puzzlearea {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
   background-image: url("planck-image.png");
}

.tile {
   font-size: 40pt;
   color: red;
   line-height: 70pt;
   width: 90px;
   height: 90px;
   border: 5px solid black;
   background-position: -200px -200px;
   position: fixed;
}
```

**Update**: [Screenshot.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54awCBW9Yx-UER3ZXRNa09QSzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Would you have any ideas as to why the positioning is not occurring?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show an image of what is happening (and possibly of what you expect). As we can't see the planck-image.png, it is tough to guess what is needed.

Comment: Ok, I've added a link to a screenshot. I'm not reputable enough to just paste the image here.

Comment: A Working example (jsfiddle.net or stacksnippets) are useful. However, your image in gdrive needs permission. Don't share like this, are not useful. Talking about your issue, **fixed positioning are attaching to the root document, not to the parent relative element**. Change to `absolute` instead

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. It should work now. I also tried changing .tile to position: absolute, but no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `position: absolute` on `.tile`in order to be able to place them with the top/bottom/left/right parameters (and you need those too).

`fixed` position refers to the viewport, not the parent element.

Comment: Ok, it seems I was missing the left/right, etc. parameters. Rookie mistake. Absolute is right. Thanks for your help!